# Calling a ros service from several nodes at the same time?

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a service that simply performs a task and then returns (i.e. it is not storing any data in global variables or retaining any type of state)....

The question is: Can I call the service from several nodes at the same time without having to worry about mutual exclusion issues? I.e. each time the service is called does it create a separate "instance" for each caller?

Thanks for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11544/calling-a-ros-service-from-several-nodes-at-the-same-time?/) by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 353 on 2011-10-13

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When calling a service, the server node will handle one call at a time and queue up the rest. Therefore, it will act on them in the same order that they were received. This is the same as if you were to publish to the same topic from multiple sources simultaneously. The messages would be placed in the queue in order that they are received.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10